# Making a custom RXJS pipe that accepts an observable and waits until that observable meets a condition

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have the following code

```
export function featureReady(feature: BaseFeatureService) {
  return pipe(
    zip(feature.loading$),
    filter(([inputObject, loading]) => !loading),
    map(([inputObject, loading]) => {
      return inputObject;
    })
  );
}
```

And I wish to consume it like this.

```
observable$.pipe(
   featureReady(this.propertyFeatureService)
);
```

`zip` is now deprecated in place of the static `zip` which means my above solution will stop working is there an RXJS operator I can replace either the `zip` operator or the whole solution with?

I would also be happy with any solution that accepts an `Observable' for the wait condition, as I wouldn't mind passing in `feature.loading$`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did some looking around other operators and found `withLatestFrom` which I can use to get the same result as I was getting from the `zip` operator above.

It now looks like this:

```
export function featureReady(feature: BaseFeatureService) {
  return pipe(
    withLatestFrom(feature.loading$),
    filter(([inputObject, loading]) => !loading),
    map(([inputObject, loading]) => {
      return inputObject;
    })
  );
}
```

I will leave the question option in case someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use skipUntil Rxjs pipeable operator which will skip value until the inner observable meet ceratin condition.

In the below code source Observable will wait until the function fun return the custom pipe which will wait until the wait observable loading status is false

```js
const { interval, timer,of,concat } = rxjs;
const {  skipUntil,delay,filter,ta } = rxjs.operators;


// Write TypeScript code!
const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>Wait until the loading status is false</h1>`;

//custom pipe function which will  until loading
const fun = (wait1) =>  skipUntil(wait1.pipe(filter(status => !status['loading'])));

console.clear()
const status = [{loading:true},{loading:false}]
//emit every 1s
const source = interval(1000);

// inner obserbale which will emit the status after certain interval
const wait1 = concat(of(status[0]).pipe(delay(1000)),of(status[1]).pipe(delay(3000))).pipe(delay(5000));
//skip emitted values from source until inner observable emits false after the loading status turned to false
const example = source.pipe(fun(wait1));

const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => appDiv.innerHTML += 'interval ' + val + '<br/>');
const subscribe1 = wait1.subscribe(val => appDiv.innerHTML += 'inner Observable status ' + val.loading + '<br/>');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

You can find the [stackBlitz solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-making-a-custom-rxjs-pipe-that-accepts-an-observable).